# replaceAll() is not replacing ™ with space in java

Tags: java

```
String url = getURL();
//getURL() returns  " /Santa-Rosa™-Comfort-Height-one-piece-compact-elongated-1.6-gpf-toilet-with-AquaPistonR-flush-technology-and-left-hand-trip-lever/productDetail/Accessories/prod170007.htm"

url= url.replaceAll("™", "");
System.out.println(url); // output: /Santa-Rosa™-Comfort-Height-one-piece-compact-elongated-1.6-gpf-toilet-with-AquaPistonR-flush-technology-and-left-hand-trip-lever/productDetail/Accessories/prod170007.htm
```

So ™ symbol is not replacing with space when I run these changes in server.But its replacing ™ with space when I run as standalone program.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I've tried the following approaches:

1. `pResponse.setContentType("text/html charset=UTF-8")`
2. set characterencodingURI to UTF-8 at server level.

Comment: Try `url= url.replaceAll("\u2122", "");` - does that help at all?

Comment: It works for me. What's your editor's text encoding? Maybe it's not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : `url= url.replaceAll("\u2122", "");`
I guess you need to use special character to replace that trademark..

Answer (score 0):

If ™ is URL-encoded, then try this approach:

```
url = url.replaceAll("%E2%84%A2", "");
```

or

```
url = URLDecoder.decode(getURL());
url= url.replaceAll("™", "");
```